# Dynamically set value in select box in React

Tags: reactjs

I have two select box in my React Application. One lists Dept. Name and other lists Employee Name of selected Department Name.

Employee Name select box is depend on Department Name select box.

```
const [deptList, setDeptList] = useState([]);
const [empList, setEmpList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getDeptLists(); //Get deptList from API
}, []);

const handleSelect = (e) => {

    if (e.target.name === 'deptListCombo') {
     getEmpList(e.target.value); //This call employee list from server based on selected dept id.
    }
 };

 const getEmpList = (deptId) => {
  //Some API call.
  setEmpList(responseData);
 };
```

I am using empList state as a menu items in empList combo, but after setting data in state I am getting

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

Comment: I don't think the `DOMException` is related to the code you've shown

Comment: Hello Codebling, I am getting this error while setting in state. I am looking a way where I can set the latest value in state and use those as a combobox list. Any help?

Comment: I don't think I can help you with only the information available in the question. DOMException should be unrelated -- you have done nothing wrong in the React code that you've shown. Are you using doing any DOM manipulations in your code somewhere, or using a special library to render your select/dropdowns?

Comment: Here you are looking for `e.target.name === 'deptListCombo'`, but as you mentioned above I think it should be `e.target.name === 'empListCombo'`

Comment: @BetterReactDeveloper that sounds incorrect. I think the goal of the code is that when a department is selected from the dropdown, then take the selected department and use it to populate the list of employees for the employee dropdown. The code in the question seems to accomplish that. Either way this will not resolve the DOMException -- there is no code here which attempts to remove a child node.